# Boost Test with CMake - undefined main

Tags: boost, cmake, boost-test

I'm having trouble building a little program that uses Boost.Test on my Mac with a Boost installed by MacPorts at `/opt/local/lib/`

Here's my minimal source file, `test.cpp`:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1) {
}
```

and my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (test)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
```

and an excerpt of from `make VERBOSE=1`:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o
g++ -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -c /Users/exclipy/Code/cpp/inline_variant/question/test.cpp
Linking CXX executable test
"/Applications/CMake 2.8-5.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
g++ -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o-o test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
  "vtable for boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t", referenced from:
      boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::unit_test_log_t() in test.cpp.o
      boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::~unit_test_log_t() in test.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
```

As you can see, it doesn't know how to link to Boost library.  So I try adding to CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(test boost_unit_test_framework)
```

But I just get:

```
g++ -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o-o test -lboost_unit_test_framework 
ld: library not found for -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

From lots of trial and error, I've found that manually running this works:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_unit_test_framework -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
```

But after hours of fiddling, I can't get it to build from CMake.  I don't care whether it links dynamically or statically, I just want it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell CMake where to find the boost libraries (the `-L/opt/local/lib` in your g++ line). You can accomplish this by adding the following line (if you had no problem with `find_package`):

```
link_directories ( ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
```

before `add_executable`.

Another alternative is using [the single-header variant of the UTF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/usage-variants/single-header-variant.html). This variant is really simple (you only need to include `<boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>` but it has a major drawback in its considerable increase in build time.

Answer (score 3):

The `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ...)` call collects the required link libraries for the searched Boost components (e.g.,`unit_test_framework`) in the CMake variable `Boost_LIBRARIES`.

To get rid of the link error, add:

```
target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT 2020-02

The details of building a Boost.Test module are on the documentation [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html) and covered with many examples on the documentation. Usually if `main` is not found, this might be due to:

- mixing static and shared library versions of Boost.Test (the linker prefers shared libraries)
- improper definitions of the [`BOOST_TEST_MODULE`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_module_macro.html) and/or [`BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_dyn_link.html) macros: depending on those, the Boost.Test framework will define (correctly) a `main` or not.

## Previous (wrong) answer

Well here, the problem is not that cmake does not find the `boost_unit_test_framework` library, but rather that this specific library does not contain the `main` entry point for running the binary.

In fact, you should link against `${Boost_TEST_EXEC_MONITOR_LIBRARY}` since it contains the proper definitions. You should also avoid defining the macro `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK`.

Comment: Note that `Boost_TEST_EXEC_MONITOR_LIBRARY` doesn't exist in (at least) the FindBoost.cmake for cmake version > 3.x.

Comment: @marco.m I've found there is a separate COMPONENT test_exec_monitor to be included to fix it

Comment: Updated this very old answer @sehe